# How can I read and open a pdf from local file in .NET MAUI?

Tags: .net, xamarin, pdf, maui

I'm migrating my Xamarin project that's using Syncfusion.PdfViewer to .NET MAUI, but its not integrated yet, there is a way to open a pdf file, from local in .NET MAUI?

Comment: What does "open" mean? Are you wanting to just read the bytes, or actually display the file?

Comment: i want to display the file, from a local .pdf file

Comment: The simple answer then is to use a web view to display the file. If you don't mind it opening in another app, you can use [Xamarin Essentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/launcher?tabs=android#files)

Comment: You can't use a web view to display a PDF in MAUI.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom webserver in the app and PDF.js (Blazor Optional for serving the JS viewer)

Here's the web server I used:
https://github.com/jchristn/WatsonWebserver/blob/master/README.md

PDF.js:
https://pdfjs.express/blog/how-to-use-pdf-js

If you use Blazor you'll need to edit the viewer.js file and modify the const HOSTED_VIEWER_ORIGINS to include "https://0.0.0.0" (for the Blazor hosted page)